# what is the point of "body" in scraper.http.HtmlResponse class constructor?

Tags: python, scrapy

this might be a super noob question...forgive me if it is....
I read that one constructs a HtmlResponse class like this:

```
response = HtmlResponse(url = 'http://asite.com', body=html, encoding='utf-8')
```

What does body=html do? Does it specify the source html? Why is the source html needed even though the url has been specified?

Comment: please remember to accept the question that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

To give context to your question, you need to understand that Scrapy is not a tool for making direct requests. Scrapy is a [web-crawling framework](https://scrapy.org/) that works on its own as a project.

I assume you think that `response = HtmlResponse(url = 'http://asite.com', ...)` could be a way to "download" information from that specific site, but that's not true. Scrapy is intended to work in a certain way and with a specific order as specified [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider). Requests and Responses are not meant to be used independently in Scrapy, as it has its own scheduler where you dump `Request` objects and you get back `Response` objects.

The `Response` objects are not meant to be instantiated directly (in fact I've never instantiated a single `Response` in my life), as they are created by the Scrapy scheduler a a "response" of the previously specified `Request`.

Haing said that, you can of course still instantiate a `Response` as any other `class` in Python, and in fact it is useful but mostly for [testing purposes](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/tests/test_http_response.py#L42), but nothing more, as it is only a "useless" representation of what should come from the Scrapy scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter **body** : To access the decoded text as str (unicode in Python 2) you can use `response.text` from an encoding-aware Response subclass, such as `TextResponse`.

For more information : [Request-Response](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because HTMLResponse doesn't download the page associated with the `url` given. `HTMLResponse` its used to parse html(to query by xpath and css). Page download happens in another piece of code. Also, with that `url` associated with `HtmlResponse` object you can access easily to that attribute.

You could check:

[https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1fd1702a11a56ecbe9851ba4f9d3c10797e262dd/scrapy/http/response/**init**.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1fd1702a11a56ecbe9851ba4f9d3c10797e262dd/scrapy/http/response/__init__.py)